# XSL apply for-each to all but one

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm currently at work on an XSL stylesheet for transforming a finding aid to html. The following line selects any instance of a head tag and lists it in my table of contents.

```
<xsl:for-each select="c01 | *[head]">
```

Say there's ONE head I'd like it not to select. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: _The following line selects any instance of a head tag_, not true, you are selecting the elements (children of the context) containing at least an `head` child tag.

Comment: What do you mean with _Say there's ONE head I'd like it not to select._ ? What you'd like be selected precisely?

Comment: @empo There's one element with a head tag that I'd like it not to affect. So while admininfo/head might show up, I'd like controlaccess/head not to. Does that make sense? Sorry, my terminology with xslt and xml is pretty weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments:

> *There's one element with a head tag that I'd like it not to affect. So while `admininfo/head` might show up, I'd like `controlaccess/head` not to.*

This is an XPath question. Use:

```
"*[head and not(self::controlaccess)]"
```

This XPath will select all elements in the context ***except*** `controlaccess` ***and*** having at least an `head` child tag.

Your final *for each but ONE*:

```
<xsl:for-each select="c01 | *[head and not(self::controlaccess)]">
```

Comment: That works beautifully. Thanks for your help! I don't think I need to do it here, but would it also be possible with something like this to select controlaccess but only the first head tag in it? Like controlaccess/head[1] only. Sorry, that's probably better reserved for a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap the inside of the for-each loop in an `xsl:if` so that the body of the loop is only applied if the current head isn't the one you want to skip.